# Is it possible to sort topics in Rizzoma by number of votes?

Tags: sorting

## Overview

As Google Moderator is shutting down on June 30, 2015 ([more Info](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sPmkuVqoHKue7SlL3tSLrDsyufB8owMeR8AHx4LG8FA/pub)) I would like to learn about alternatives, mainly for educators. [Rizzoma](http://rizzoma.com) topics could include the Yes/No/Maybe Wave gadget, so topics could work as Google Moderator submissions.

## Question

Is it possible to sort topics by number of votes gathered through the Yes/No/Maybe Wave gadget?

## References

[Alternatives for Google Moderator / Moderator for Google Apps - Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20484/alternatives-for-google-moderator-moderator-for-google-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time it's not possible to change the sort order of [Rizzoma](http://rizzoma.com) topics, so sorting of topics by a gadget attribute is not possible either.

One alternative could be to develop a Wave gadget to be used as a topic container where users could submit items to be voted and lately sorted.

**References**
https://rizzoma.com/help-center-faq.html